# Mobile UX for a list of questions with editable answers?

Tags: mobile, scrolling, collapsible-panels

As part of a larger app, I am designing a mobile UX for a fixed list of 30 questions that the app user can answer. The user can answer from 0 to 30 questions, averaging around 3 answers. They can edit/delete/add answers at any time, averaging around an edit every 5th session. Questions are short, one sentence each. Answers are long, 100 to 1000 characters each.

What UX pattern can I use for such list?

I have a few ideas, but I don't like any of them:

1. A screen with a scrollable list of questions. A click on the question opens another screen with editable field for the answer. I don't like this because it takes a lot of clicking back and forth to answer several questions.
2. A screen with a scrollable list of questions and answers. Answers are immediately below questions in editable fields. I don't like this because it's easy to loose track of short questions among a sheet of long answers. Also, will scrolling a bunch of editable fields be confusing?
3. A screen with a scrollable list of questions and answers. Answers are collapsed. Clicking on the question uncollapses the editable field that contains the answer. Same cons as #2. Plus if there are many answers, collapsing/uncollapsing each is annoying.

Are their UX best practices here? Anything you can suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. New screen for each question Avoided here.
2. Added [Scrollspy Vertical Menu](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_scrollspy2&stacked=h) on left labeled with numbers which will help in scrolling through 30 questions. Answered question are marked with letter 'A'.
3. Avoided collapsibles.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, neat idea! A scroll with a content built in.